# How to add service account and inti container info in new helm chart 16.2?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I want to add service account and initconatiner in helm chart 16.2.

I tried to add in pu-statefulset.yaml of xap-pu. getting error.

I also tried to add in pu-crd.yaml which was successfully installed but not reflate on pod yaml.

Comment: What errors do you receive? Please also give details on your environment - what version of Kubernetes is it, is it bare-metal/cloud provider?

Comment: feel free to post the new question with helm chart details and link, or some YAML so other can get the idea, of what error you are getting and all. closing this question.